# NodaTime and Ancient Times

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm working with some values from WikiPedia that are in some cases Million of years ago (Like the formation of the moon, which WikiData reports as being formed: "-4527000000-01-01T00:00:00Z". In other case I'm simply looking at years that might be 10000 B.C.  etc., still expressed as "-10000-01-01T00:00:00Z".

As far as I could figure out testing NodaTime, and reading the documentation, these  ancient years are not supported (OR I overlooked something). For example, this fails:

```
OffsetDateTime defaultValue = new OffsetDateTime(new LocalDateTime(77, 1, 1, 0, 0), Offset.Zero);
var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultValue);
string P = "-1000-01-25T20:34:25Z";
var result = pattern.Parse(P);

NodaTime.Text.UnparsableValueException: The value string includes a negative value where only a non-negative one is allowed. Value being parsed: '^-1000-01-25T20:34:25Z'. (^ indicates error position.)
   at NodaTime.Text.ParseResult`1.GetValueOrThrow() in C:\Users\jon\Test\Projects\nodatime\build\releasebuild\src\NodaTime\Text\ParseResult.cs:line 81
   at TryNodaTime.Program.Main(String[] args
```

using sing this string works fine btw: string P = "1000-01-25T20:34:25Z";

I'm hoping I just overlooked something obvious as to handle very large old dates/years. Other examples includes old cities btw, which have exact date from long before year 0.

Guidance on how to handle these would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Found this example, which requires me to first detect the year manually, and then use LocalDate if it's negative, however, doesn't solve the larger issue here as it fails below -9999:

```
LocalDate BCDATE = new LocalDate(Era.BeforeCommon, -15000, 10, 1);
Console.WriteLine($"BC: {BCDATE}");
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you write your own AncientTime struct.  Model it after the .NET DateTime (and TimeSpan), but strip it down to just what you need.  For example, if you care about millions of years, you probably don't care about timezones, and you probably don't need to have the precision that DateTime has.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that you don't need more than 1 second precision (by the way, 4.5 billion years is about 142,000,000,000,000,000 seconds (about 1.4 times 10 to the 17th, if my rough calculations are right)).  You should be able to fit about +/- 292,000,000,000 years into a signed 64 bit integer full of seconds.  Of course time calculations are a pain - for example, the lengths of years were calculated differently before the 1600s (and there is no year zero!).  You need to decide what you really want to do

Comment: You are correct FlyDog, I absolutely won't need the extra precision, it's basically just the year once I go that far back. I was simply hoping that NodaTime could just 'support' *any* year, be it 45 million years ago or 1971. It's easier if my library of choice has a way to 'just handle it'. If course, it may very well be I have to write my own, I'm sort of expecting to at this point, but hoping none-the-less.

Comment: I'm totally OK if NodaTime simply supports just dates (or even months or years) for ancient times (Discard everyting else), as long as I can use the library without worrying about the actual numbers. For example, if it simply ignored anything smaller than a day when the year is < -9999, that would go a long way... Just thinking out loud here .. I've only used the library for about 3 hours...

Comment: If you are working in millions of years then months, days, hours, etc, fade into insignificance. You might as well just use `long` or `BigInteger` to represent your year. But if you do need to represent parts of years then `BigRational` is an awesome option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noda Time doesn't support ancient or far future values.

The range of values supported is [in the user guide](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/range).

> Noda Time can only represent values within a limited range. This is for pragmatic reasons: while it would be possible to try to model every instant since some estimate of the big bang until some expected "end of time," this would come at a significant cost to the experience of the 99.99% of programmers who just need to deal with dates and times in a reasonably modern (but not far-flung future) era.
>
> The Noda Time 1.x releases supported years between around -27000 and +32000 (in the Gregorian calendar), but had significant issues around the extremes. Noda Time 2.0 has a smaller range, with more clearly-defined behaviour.
>
> ...
>
> Additionally, all calendars are restricted to four digit formats, even in year-of-era representations, which avoids ever having to parse 5-digit years. This leads to a Gregorian calendar from 9999 BCE to 9999 CE inclusive, or -9998 to 9999 in "absolute" years. The range of other calendars is determined from this and from natural restrictions (such as not being proleptic).

I'm afraid I think it may well be better not to use Noda Time at all for this use case, rather than trying to work around it - unless you're okay with effectively reporting the far-distant dates verbatim and doing no other work with them.

Sorry about this - it's one of those situations where trying to support *all* use cases does harm to the far more common use case :(

Comment: For times that are prehistoric, or nearly so, and also for the distant future, the difference between a day being defined by one sunrise coupled with one sunset, and a day being defined by 86400 atomic seconds, starts to become a serious issue. Since Nodatime has no way to represent this distinction, these cuttoff limits are probably appropriate.

Comment: @GerardAshton: Indeed, I'd expect all kinds of "somewhat niche" aspects of functionality, e.g. dates that are only defined relative to other dates, or with a degree of ambiguity etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that sort of what I figured although I missed that comment. I'm trying to write some rather pragmatic code that just 'works' with whatever input I'm throwing at it, so I'll instead encapsulate NodaTime with a few other special cases. I'm generally merging inputs from potentially thousands of API's, and just trying to make it all as automatic as can-be, including these weird ancient dates. Still trying to wrap my head around NodaTime in general :).